# JPA Table generation problems

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I'm having trouble with JPA. When I try to persist a new entity I will get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: Technology is not a known
>   entity type.

Technology is the title of the Category class. (Note: my code has worked before!) So I decided to drop all tables in the database (PostgreSql)

N̶o̶w̶ ̶I̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶l̶l̶o̶w̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶:̶

(I've had this error before, but it dissapeared after a while)
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "category" does not exist
  Position: 47
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT ID, DESCRIPTION, TITLE, PARENT_ID FROM category
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Category sql="SELECT ID, DESCRIPTION, TITLE, PARENT_ID FROM category")

**Entity class (Category.Java)**

```
@Entity
public class Category implements DataObject, Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue 
private Long id;
private String title;
private String description;

@ManyToOne @JsonIgnore 
private Category parent;

@Transient
private Long parentId;
//functions
}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
  <persistence-unit name="BloggerPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>blogdb</jta-data-source>
    <class>domain.Blog</class>
    <class>domain.BlogUser</class>
    <class>domain.Category</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

**Edit**

I solved the relation ERROR by restarting the glassfish server.
Now I'm back at the first error.

**DatabaseJPA.java**

```
public class DatabaseJPA<T extends DataObject> implements Database<T> {

private EntityManagerFactory factory;
private EntityManager manager;
private Class<T> type;

public DatabaseJPA(String name, Class<T> type)
{
      factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(name);
      manager = factory.createEntityManager();
      this.type = type;
}
@Override
public T ReadValue(long id) {

   return (T) manager.find(type, id);
}

@Override
public void InsertValue(T value) {


    manager.getTransaction().begin();

    manager.persist(value);

    manager.flush();
    manager.getTransaction().commit();

}

@Override
public void UpdateValue(long id, T value) {
    manager.getTransaction().begin();
    manager.merge(value);
    manager.flush();
    manager.getTransaction().commit();
}


@Override
public void DeleteValue(long id) {
    manager.getTransaction().begin();
    manager.remove(this.ReadValue(id));
    manager.flush();
    manager.getTransaction().commit();
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    factory.close();
    manager.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Well maybe I don't understand something but if you don't have any tables in your db then what do you expect when you call select from category if your table called category doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes but JPA should automatically generate the tables based on the properties of the Entity

Comment: Can you show how you are trying to persist entity causing a problem?

Comment: I've added my db class

Comment: Ok, so now show us how you are trying to call your InsertValue method - what you are passing there.

Comment: I just add a instance of Category.java -> Which is first valided by a validator

Comment: JPA DDL creation only works at intial deployment, which is why you need to restart the server after dropping the tables.  drop-and-create I hope is only used for testing and doesn't get left in

Comment: "IllegalArgumentException: <X> is not a known entity type." occurs when you have a classloading issue, such as if you never close your factories but redeploy the application.  The old factory will exist and get used underneath any new factories, and it doesn't recognize the entities load by the new classloader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `transaction-type` to `LOCAL_RESOURCE` in persistence.xml solved the issue and restarting the glassfish server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have relation problem again:

```
@ManyToOne
private A parent;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
private Collection<A> children;
```

For the IllegalArgumentException can you show us a portion of code where you call your persist and it raises the exception ?

Comment: <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/> This property should create the database tables on startup

Comment: are you using jpa 2.1 i dont see it in you persistence.xml ? You should have "version='2.1'" in <persistence/>

Comment: Yes i have the persistence tag just did not include it, I only included the persistence unit in my question

Comment: and so what version of JPA are you using ?

Comment: I'm using version 2.1

Comment: The code for pesisting an entity is in my question, as for the exception it is caught by glassfish. Also I don't think it a relation problem since I cannot persist objects without relations to other object Like my user (which only contains strings)

Comment: Yes the method is in your question. Not the code raising the exception

Comment: The code raising the exception is in the JPA libraries. But I have just found the soloution.